# Is there is a way in WPF to restrict resource usage as StaticResource?

Tags: wpf

I have an application that using different translated text from ResourceDictionaries (lang.xaml, lang.en-GB.xaml, etc), which is defined in my App.xaml like this:

```
<Application x:Class="AppName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="LangEngDictionary" Source="Resources/lang.xaml" />          
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And there is a place in ui where user can change current UI language. The problem is I have to use

```
Text="{DynamicResource translated_field_label}"
```

instead of using

```
Text="{StaticResource translated_field_label}"
```

, because StaticResource can't be reloaded in runtime. So I have a lot of errors with usage **StaticResource** in such places, typed without attention.
The question is: Is there is a way to restrict using some ResourceDictionary as StaticResource?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "restrict".

Comment: I find the question rather confusing.  You should use dynamicresource and ensure you start with a resource dictionary provides values for all the keys. When they want to change language, merge in a resource dictionary with entries have the same keys but the translated strings. Application.current.resources is a sort of a hash table so you then overlay with your new values.

Comment: So you want to avoid accidentally referencing these string resources using "StaticResource", and only allow them to be used in conjunction with "DynamicResource"? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No
`StaticResource` always be a `static` things, the object should not be changed when running.
[Edit for clear] - Because using `StaticResource` to referencing a resource, the target property is a direct referenced to the object of "target resource" and has no association with the "Resource Key".
Just like this:

```
<TargetObject x:Key="ResourceKey"/>
... Property="{StaticResource ResourceKey}" ...
```

Is equals to

```
var ResourceKey = new TargetObject();
MyObject.Property = ResourceKey;
```

Therefore, after the first assigned, you can no longer modify the referenced object of target proprety by changing the referenced object associated with the key in the resource dictionary.

So, you should use the `DynamicResource` for may changed resource.

---

I used to very excluding to use `DynamicResource` - but finally I understand: now that the performance permits, why should I be bothered by using`StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`?